# Do the same phone models with different version have different modem hardware?

Tags: hardware, rom, baseband, telephony

Many phones have different variants for different regions: India, China, N.A., Global, etc. Apart from eSIM support and ISP restriction (like AT&T in the US), the supported radio bands are often different.

I wonder if this is caused by hardware or software? For example, if the Global version supports certain LTE bands, while the Indian version doesn't, will flashing ROM (or flashing modem) enable those bands?

Comment: Different supported bands means different frequencies. The antenna is the component that has major impact on which frequencies are amplified and which are weakened, therefore emy guess ist that at least the antennas are different.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. I removed the secondary question because it makes the question unfocused (multiple unrelated questions) and the nature of the question itself is so broad (e.g. software supports, ROM features, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Phones are manufactured for different countries to support not only the bands that are used there but also the regulations.  For instance I had a phone from the middle east once, where I could not remove the Muslim holidays from my calendar!  And even though EEG hardware has been on the Samsung watches for a while, this is disabled in certain countries where they dont yet have permission to use.

It is quite a common problem (even on this site), where people have purchased a phone meant for a different country.   At the very least this means that the antennas are different. Which means that the phone may not support all the bands available in the 2nd country.